How to solve or suppress Gtk-Warnings when opening a website in Java?
I am currently working on a larger project but was able to pin point my problem to one line:
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://google.com"));


When attempting to open a website using the java.awt.Desktop class in Java, such as Google, the following GTK warning is printed to my console twice. How do I solve or suppress this warning?
[146880, Main Thread] WARNING: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/4090/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.: 'glib warning', file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:187

(firefox:146880): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:05:50.793: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/4090/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 21:05:50.793: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"


I followed this post and attempted to resolve the issue by installing, removing, and reinstalling the module, but the warning persists.
I started and tried to suppress the warning, but I have not found any option in Firefox to disable the warning.
Additionally, the command export GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge did not successfully suppress the Gtk warning generated by Firefox.
I also tried redirecting the standard error stream using System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/dev/null")));, but this did not resolve the issue.

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Firefox 124.0.2 (64-bit)
Any idea is appreciated.

"3... command export GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge did not successfully suppress" - it needs the opposite, unset that with GTK_MODULES= firefox

Using GTK_MODULES= firefox in the terminal started firefox and the warnings are still there.

That line suppresses only first warning "Not loading module atk-bridge: the functionality is provided by GTK natively" but all other warnings. Have you tried firefox built (.deb) from its official firefox repo? Suppose those messages are common to containerised ones (snap/flatpak) only.

Thanks, that's it. I start to hate snap more and more ...

Like mentioned by yvs2014 the message only occurs when installing Firefox via snap, like in my case, and probably when installing via flatpak. To solve the problem simply follow the official download provided by Mozilla and use .deb.
Caution: Remember to back up your settings, passwords, profiles, etc. before reinstalling.

I'm wondering if the problem is really linked to an app.
This thread is mentioning Firefox, but I saw many others mentioning a bunch of other apps.
I'm personally facing a similar issue with "cheese" and other apps.:

f5nkj@f5nkj-Green-G4:~$ cheese Gtk-Message: 19:45:34.079: Not loading
module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively.
Please try to not load it.
(cheese:381688): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:45:34.149: GTK+ module
/snap/cheese/40/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
cannot be loaded. GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3
in the same process is not supported. Gtk-Message: 19:45:34.149:
Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

So, if this is a more generic problem, it would be great if someone knows how to get rid of it, or at least to prevent trying to load the module

Please try to not load it.

Note: I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

It seems that the issue might be related to Snap rather than the specific application itself. If I'm not mistaken, you installed Cheese using Snap. Have you considered installing it using a different method?

Hello,
I installed it using "sudo apt install cheese".
Not sure if it uses snap or not...
I see the app starting and my face appears on-screen, but then, a second or two after, my face disappears and is replaced by a message saying there is a problem streaming from the camera...
If a terminal is open, I see the warnings already reported, the last one being fatal. I can't copy all of it because I'm limited in numbers of characters I can type in this window...

It seems that you installed cheese via snap, as indicated by the /snap/cheese path in your second warning. To confirm this, you can use the following commands in the terminal:
First, use which cheese to check the installation path. If the output is /usr/bin/cheese, then cheese was installed via apt. However, if the output is /snap/bin/cheese, it means cheese was installed via snap. Additionally, you can run the whereis cheese command, which will show all the locations related to cheese. If you see paths such as /snap/bin/cheese remove the snap version and install cheese using apt.

Hi Zipity,
The command you shared are very useful. I add them in my "preferred list". (I'm not a Linux expert - yet).
I confirm cheese was installed using snap. Furthermore, I removed it and reinstalled via apt. And it works like a charm.
All warnings disappeared and "my face" stays on screen. I'll now will be able to see what this application can do.
So I guess your first assessment was the right one: the problem is with snap.
A great thank you for helping on that matter.
